# How to debug an array issue in my program?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, minesweeper

I have been trying to program minesweeper in pygame as my first ever video game.

I have been trying to create an array that tells me on every pixel how many bombs is there in a radius of 3x3 by checking inside of another array that generates 10 bombs on a 10 by 8 grid. (The array is actually 12 by 10 so that if you check a bomb on the corner and it tries to check the places before the position 0,0 it doesn't crash).

But no matter what I do I can't make it work.

```
import random
import numpy as np
num_bomb = 10
num_cell_x = 10
num_cell_y = 8
bombs = np.zeros([int(num_cell_y+2),int(num_cell_x+2)],dtype = np.uint)
for i in range(num_bomb):
        bombs[random.randint(1,num_cell_y),random.randint(1,num_cell_x)] = 1
num_bombs = np.zeros([num_cell_y,num_cell_x],dtype = np.uint)
# The part that doesn't work:
for x in range(0,num_cell_x):
    for y in range(0,num_cell_y):
        bomb_count = 0
        if bombs[y,x] == 0:
            for sy in range(y-1,y+1):
                for sx in range(x-1,x+1):
                    if bombs[sy,sx] == 1:
                        num_bombs[y,x] += 1

print(bombs)
print()
print(num_bombs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range(a, b)` generated the number sin range [a, b[ respectively all numbers >= `a` but < `b`. Therefore you have to generate the ranges `range(y-1,y+2)` and `range(x-1,x+2)` instead of `range(y-1,y+1)` and `range(x-1,x+1)`:

```py
for sy in range(y-1,y+2):
    for sx in range(x-1,x+2):
        # [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think easiest way to do what you want would be to use convolution 2D with kernel np.ones((3, 3))

```
import scipy.signal
num_bombs = scipy.signal.convolve2d(bombs, np.ones((3, 3), mode='same')
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html